# How to get rid of all previous git commits without losing changes

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I made a lot of little commits and now I want to get rid of them all from the history so that if I do git log it only shows one commit at most. But I don't want to lose any of the changes I made. So basically my last commit becomes like the initial commit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git rebase -i` and mark all commits (except the first one) with `s`, that means squash. All commits will be squashed into one.

Note, that by doing this, you are rewriting history, and if this is a public repository, it will affect anyone who already pulled from the repo.